Migrate WebPush from legacy FCM APIs to HTTP v1 give "Requested entity was not found." error 404
I am migrating our WebPush APP from FCM APIs to HTTP v1. In updating the payload of send request I target specific devices, and it gives:
{
  code: 404,
  message: 'Requested entity was not found.',
  status: 'NOT_FOUND',
  details: [
    {
      '@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmError',
      errorCode: 'UNREGISTERED'
    }
  ]
}

But if I'm sending to the same token from the same project via https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/ it works. What is wrong I do with HTTP v1 ?
As I read it must work with the same browser token, but it is not.

Running into the exact same issue, did you find a solution?
